# Safari extension: listen for page load/update

Tags: safari-extension

I am testing a little extenstion programming for Safari.
In the global HTML background page I have a script which needs to call a function each time the page is loaded or updated.

I have tested a little with extensions on Chrome and in Chrome I can listen for page updates like this

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(myFunction);
```

The question is how can I do the same thing in Safari?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Windows and Tabs API for this. [Info here](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH17-SW5). Safari windows and tabs send events when they refresh, change URL etc. Does this help? I have done some extension development, but it has been a while.